# Rateit not working on safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, safari

I don't understand why my rateit plugin doesn't work on safari, but in the official website of rateit, it works. Here is a jsfiddle of my problem, only in safari browser

```
jsfiddle.net/fyncf9j3/2/
```

It returns a TypeError: Type error

official example page:
[official example page](http://ttp://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm)

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: My problem is mark on my subject i have a ErrorType: Type error with my code only on safari, other browser work fine

Comment: i follow a jsfiddle for reproduce with minimum code, see link on the subject. 

Regards

Comment: Ya, but you **have** to post relevant code in question itself, that's hoiw it works here on SO. Once your jsFiddle link will be down (and that will happen soon or later), this question wouldn't be helpful for any futur readers

Comment: link of jsfiddle work perfectly

Comment: You didn't understand what i mean and btw still doesn't have read SO rules, what can i say?...

Comment: Ok i solved the problem, it's because i make an object in parameter, but it's only accept attribute